# Replace or mirror a url from another url using htacess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, woocommerce

i have a website that is built in wordpress and i have a url

`www.mywebsite.com/product/my-new-product`  so what i need is i want to remove `/product` from url . i want `www.mywebsite.com/my-new-product` .

or is it possible that some one click on `www.mywebsite.com/my-new-product` then it will show the content of `www.mywebsite.com/product/my-new-product`

Please check

i tired the following but it also not working

```
 RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/product/my-new-product$ /my-new-product/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewriting works the other way round than what you apparently expect. It works on *incoming* requests, so you need to rewrite the URL you want to see in the browsers address bar to what internally is required on the server side:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?my-new-product/(.*)$ /product/my-new-product/$1 [END]
```

To keep the desired URL in the browsers address bar you also need to take care that the page uses relative references. So not absolute ones referring to `/product/my-new-product/...` but only to `/my-new-product`. That is outside the scope of rewriting, though.

In case you receive an internal server error (http status 500) using the rule above then chances are that you operate a very old version of the apache http server. You will see a definite hint to an unsupported `[END]` flag in your http servers error log file in that case. You can either try to upgrade or use the older `[L]` flag, it probably will work the same in this situation, though that depends a bit on your setup.

This rule will work likewise in the http servers host configuration or inside a dynamic configuration file (".htaccess" file). Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded inside the http server and enabled in the http host. In case you use a dynamic configuration file you need to take care that it's interpretation is enabled at all in the host configuration and that it is located in the host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (".htaccess"). Those dynamic configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).